# KeystoneJs user-defined order for Relationship

Tags: postgresql, graphql, keystonejs

I am using KeystoneJS with PostgreSQL as my backend and Apollo on the frontend for my app.
I have a schema that has a list that is linked to another list.
I want to be able to allow users to change the order of the second list.

This is a simplified version of my schema

```js
keystone.createList(
    'forms',
    {
      fields: {
        name: {
          type: Text,
          isRequired: true,
        },
        buttons: {
          type: Relationship,
          ref: 'buttons.attached_forms',
          many: true,
        },
      },
    }
);

keystone.createList(
    'buttons',
    {
      fields: {
        name: {
          type: Text,
          isRequired: true,
        },
        attached_forms: {
          type: Relationship,
          ref: 'forms.buttons',
          many: true,
        },
      },
    }
);
```

So what I would like to do, is allow users to change the order of buttons so when I fetch them in the future from forms:

```js
const QUERY = gql`
  query getForms($formId: ID!) {
    allforms(where: {
      id: $formId,
    }) {
      id
      name
      buttons {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The buttons should come back from the backend in a predefined order.

```js
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Form 1',
    buttons: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Button 1',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Button 3',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Button 2',
        }
    ]
}
```

Or even just have some data on that returns with the query that will allow for sorting according to the user-defined sort order on the frontend.

The catch is that this relationship is many to many.

So it wouldn't be enough to add a column to the buttons schema as the ordering needs to be relationship-specific. In other words, if a user puts a particular button last on a particular form, it shouldn't change the order of that same button on other forms.

In a backend that I was creating myself, I would add something to the joining table, like a `sortOrder` field or similar and then change those values to change the order, or even order them on the frontend using that information.
Something like [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49956113/921266).
The many-to-many join table would have columns like formId, buttonId, sortOrder.

I have been diving into the docs for KeystoneJS and I can't figure out a way to make this work without getting into the weeds of overriding the KnexAdapter that we are using.

I am using:

```js
{
    "@keystonejs/adapter-knex": "^11.0.7",
    "@keystonejs/app-admin-ui": "^7.3.11",
    "@keystonejs/app-graphql": "^6.2.1",
    "@keystonejs/fields": "^20.1.2",
    "@keystonejs/keystone": "^17.1.2",
    "@keystonejs/server-side-graphql-client": "^1.1.2",
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to have two "button" lists, one with a template for a button  (`buttonTemplate` below) with common data such as name etc, and another (`button` below) which references one `buttonTemplate` and one `form`. This allows you to assign a `formIndex` property to each `button`, which dictates its position on the corresponding form.

(Untested) example code:

```
keystone.createList(
  'Form',
  {
    fields: {
      name: {
        type: Text,
        isRequired: true,
      },
      buttons: {
        type: Relationship,
        ref: 'Button.form',
        many: true,
      },
    },
  }
);

keystone.createList(
  'Button',
  {
    fields: {
      buttonTemplate: {
        type: Relationship,
        ref: 'ButtonTemplate.buttons',
        many: false,
      },
      form: {
        type: Relationship,
        ref: 'Form.buttons',
        many: false,
      },
      formIndex: {
        type: Integer,
        isRequired: true,
      },
    },
  }
);

keystone.createList(
  'ButtonTemplate',
  {
    fields: {
      name: {
        type: Text,
        isRequired: true,
      },
      buttons: {
        type: Relationship,
        ref: 'Button.buttonTemplate',
        many: true,
      },
    },
  }
);
```

I think this is less likely to cause you headaches (which I'm sure you can see coming) down the line than your `buttonOrder` solution, e.g. users deleting buttons that are referenced by this field.

If you do decide to go with this approach, you can guard against such issues with the [hook functionality](https://www.keystonejs.com/api/hooks) in Keystone. E.g. before a `button` is [deleted](https://www.keystonejs.com/api/hooks/#beforedelete), go through all the forms and rewrite the `buttonOrder` field, removing any references to the deleted button.

Comment: Nice. So you add the missing middle table as a whole new list. I hadn't thought of that. I guess the downside is that now instead of 3 tables (2 tables and a join) it now has 5 tables (2 tables, the joining table and the actual joining tables between them), so performance might become an issue, but you are totally right. this seems like a good way to work around the limitations. Thank you.

Comment: NP. You might be able to avoid a performance hit by copying the attributes from your button templates to each button as it's created, so you only need to reference the templates once for each button - example of copying data here https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/server-side-graphql-client/#use-cases

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar challenge once, so after some research and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838729/how-to-implement-priorities-in-sql-postgres), I implemented a solution to a project using PostgreSQL TRIGGER.

So you can add a trigger where on an update, it should shift the `buttonOrder`.

Here is the SQL I had on me, this was the test code, I regex replaced the terms to fit your question :)

```js
    // Assign order
    await knex.raw(`
        do $$
        DECLARE form_id text;
        begin
            CREATE SEQUENCE buttons_order_seq;
            CREATE VIEW buttons_view AS SELECT * FROM "buttons" ORDER BY "createdAt" ASC, "formId";
            CREATE RULE buttons_rule AS ON UPDATE TO buttons_view DO INSTEAD UPDATE buttons SET order = NEW.order WHERE id = NEW.id;
        
            FOR form_id IN SELECT id FROM form LOOP
                ALTER SEQUENCE buttons_order_seq RESTART;
        
                UPDATE buttons_view SET order = nextval('buttons_order_seq') WHERE "formId" = form_id;
            END LOOP;
        
            DROP SEQUENCE buttons_order_seq;
            DROP RULE buttons_rule ON buttons_view;
            DROP VIEW buttons_view;
        END; $$`);

    // Create function that shifts orders
    await knex.raw(`
        CREATE FUNCTION shift_buttons_order()
            RETURNS trigger AS
            $$
            BEGIN
                IF NEW.order < OLD.order THEN
                    UPDATE buttons SET order = order + 1, "shiftOrderFlag" = NOT "shiftOrderFlag"
                        WHERE order >= NEW.order AND order < OLD.order AND "formId" = OLD."formId";
                ELSE 
                    UPDATE buttons SET order = order - 1, "shiftOrderFlag" = NOT "shiftOrderFlag"
                        WHERE order <= NEW.order AND order > OLD.order AND "formId" = OLD."formId";
                END IF;
            RETURN NEW;
            END;
            $$
            LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'`);

    // Create trigger to shift orders on update
    await knex.raw(`
        CREATE TRIGGER shift_buttons_order BEFORE UPDATE OF order ON buttons FOR EACH ROW
            WHEN (OLD."shiftOrderFlag" = NEW."shiftOrderFlag" AND OLD.order <> NEW.order)
            EXECUTE PROCEDURE shift_buttons_order()`);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option that we came up with is to add the order to the form table.

```js
keystone.createList(
    'forms',
    {
      fields: {
        name: {
          type: Text,
          isRequired: true,
        },
        buttonOrder: {
          type: Text,
        },
        buttons: {
          type: Relationship,
          ref: 'buttons.attached_forms',
          many: true,
        },
      },
    }
);
```

This new field `buttonOrder` could contain a string representation of the order of the button Ids, like in a JSON stringified array.
The main issue with this is that it will be difficult to keep this field in-sync with the actual linked buttons.